# fread from mouseevent returns 3 bytes instead of 16, sizeof(input_event)

Tags: linux, mouse, mouseevent

Following the tutorial on using mouse input for robot odometry (http://web.me.com/haroldsoh/tutorials/technical-skills/using-optical-mice-for-othe-2/) I created a udev rule to identify the mouse as a custom input device, and I call it /dev/odoml & /dev/odomr.

/etc/udev/rules.d/90-odom.rules:

> SUBSYSTEMS=="input" ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:1d.2-1/input0", NAME="odoml"

the usb port identifies the mouse. Now i try to read the mouse input in c:

> int f = open("dev/odoml", O_RDONLY);
>   input_event ev;
>   int read_byes = (f, &ev, sizeof(input_event));

My problem is that most of the time i am getting incomplete 3 instead of the expected 16 bytes of input_event. 
Unplugging the mouse seems to change things: every 10 times the mouse works as expected. Once the mouse is plugged and read() correctly reads 16 bytes, the mouse remains working between executions of the program. If the mouse doesn't work, it won't start working until i replug it and have luck -- 1 out of ~10. I can't see any regularity in how it fails.

The file opens correctly every time.   cat /dev/odoml  displays *less* data when the mouse stops working. Opening the device with O_DIRECT fails. O_ASYNC, O_NDELAY don't help -- it's either -1 or 3. I checked it on 4 different mice, 3 of them behaved in this erroneous way.

Please help or point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` subsystem provides several interfaces.  The one you're reading from is the legacy mouse interface, which provides a `/dev/psaux`-style mouse device.  (These are usually created as `/dev/input/mouse*` devices).

The one you *want* is the event interface for the mouse, which is usually created as `/dev/input/event*`.  That's the one that provides the 16-byte `struct input_event` frames.

You'll have to tweak your `udev` rule to pick up the "event" device rather than the "mouse" device.  Try adding this condition:

```
KERNEL=="event[0-9]*"
```